# How to close my app after it's finished uploading if it's instantiated from the share function

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app, I allow content sharing (images or text) via other apps. I've done this by following the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

When the user attempts to share something via other apps (and if the application is closed), I have to do these steps:

1. Login the user
2. Initialize some basic information from the server
3. Take them to a screen where they can enter the title of whatever they're sharing + the content that was supplied from the other app that instantiated the sharing
4. Allow the user to press a button to upload this to the server.

The problem is, whilst the above steps are all working fine, I've not been able to find a way to terminate my app after the upload has completed. This means, my app sits on top of the other app (that started the share intent) and the user has no way of getting back to the original app unless they press the back button a few times.

What I would ideally like to do is to close my app immediately after the sharing is done (or cancelled) and take the users back to the original app.

What I've tried so far:

1. I tried to raise an intent to the `ShareActivity` (the main activity that handles sharing) after upload is finished and then call `onFinish` on that one but unfortunately that simply takes me back to upload activity again which is the previous activity in the stack. The `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` that's used in the intent does not seem to have any effect here for whatever reason even though the ShareActivity should be a parent activity in the activity stack.
2. I've tried to call `system.exit(0)` on the ShareActivity (that was instantiated using the intent mentioned in (1). This simply restarts my app completely whilst still sitting on top of the app that started the sharing.

I really don't know what else I can do to force my app to shutdown. I know I should let Android do whatever it wants with regards to taking care of application's lifecycle and I'm perfectly happy with that as long as my app is opened in a standalone mode.

This is different however in that I believe my app should definitely shutdown completely after sharing has finished.

I'm sure there must be a way to do this which is why I'm asking the question here in case someone has already come across this problem before and is able to help me with it.

Many thanks,

Comment: You just need to finish all your activities to return the user to where he was before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing in an argument (`shouldExit`) to all the previous activities in the bundle and checked this argument on the onCreate() and if so, I called `finish()`. Not ideal since there were quite a few activities in the chain but at least it works.